# Interesting sequence of all the natural numbers

Tags: soft-question, permutations

What are some sequences that contain all of the natural numbers that come up naturally in mathematics? (Obviously, there are an infinite number of sequences of all the natural numbers ($2^{\aleph_0}$ to be exact).)

Ideally, I'm looking for sequences that contain each natural number exactly once.

(Oh, and just to get it out of the way, $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots$)

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be any permutation on $\mathbb N$. Then $\sigma(1),\sigma(2),...$, categorizes all of them.

Comment: You should put "interesting" somewhere in the body of your question (not just the title) to make it clearer that you are asking a soft question.

Answer (score 2):

The [Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) is a great source for interesting integer sequences. You will find some pointers relevant to your question [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Permutation_of_the_nonnegative_integers).